# Proving a measure is equal to the Lebesgue

Tags: measure-theory

I wish to show that if a Measure $\mu$ satisfies  $\mu((a,b]) = b-a$  for any $a,b$ where $b-a\in\mathbb{Q}$ then $\mu = \lambda$ on the Borel sigma. Where $\lambda$ denotes the Lebesgue Measure.

My proof consists of the following steps:

1. Show that $\mu((a,b]) = b-a$ for any $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$
2. Use the above to show $\mu = \lambda$

**Part 1**

For any $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$
define $A_n := \{ \epsilon \in (\frac{1}{n} , \frac{1}{n+1}) : b-(a-\epsilon) \in \mathbb{Q}  \}$ Which because of the density of rationals is non empty.

And as such define a sequence $\epsilon_1 , \epsilon_2 ,... $ by selecting any element of $A_n$ for $\epsilon_n$

In summary the sequence $\{\epsilon_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is defined such that it satisfies the following two properites:

Firstly $\frac{1}{n} < \epsilon_n < \frac{1}{n+1}$ and that $b-(a-\epsilon_n) \in \mathbb{Q}$ for all $n$

Now define $f_n(x) : = \chi_{(a-\epsilon_n,b]}(x)$ and notice that the $f_n $ are non-negative, measurable, increasing and have the limit $\chi_{(a,b]}(x)$

By the Monotone Convergence Theorem we have:

$\lim_{n\to \infty} \int f_n d\mu = \int \lim_{n\to\infty} f_n d\mu$

The RHS is simply $\int \lim_{n\to\infty} f_n d\mu = \int \chi_{(a,b]} d\mu = \mu((a,b]) 
$

And the LHS is $\lim_{n\to \infty} \int f_n d\mu = \lim_{n\to\infty} \int \chi_{(a-\epsilon_n,b]} d\mu = \lim_{n\to\infty} \mu((a-\epsilon_n,b]) = \lim_{n\to\infty} b-a+\epsilon_n =b-a$ as our assumption of $\mu((x,y]) = y-x$ for $y-x \in \mathbb{Q}$ and the careful deffinition of $\epsilon_n$

Hence $\mu((a,b]) = b-a$ and we are done for this part.

**Part 2**

So µ and λ agree on all intervals of the form (a,b] and the Borel σ-algebra
is the smallest sigma generated by intervals  of the
form (a,b]. Which gives us $\mu = \lambda$ on Borel sets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution seems right but you are overcomplicating in the first part. This is a similar proof but without integrals.

Let $a,b\in \mathbb Q $, then $b-a\in \mathbb Q $. Now: as the real numbers is the set where every Cauchy sequence of rational numbers converges then given $c,d\in \mathbb{R}$ there are monotone sequences of rationals such that $a_n \downarrow c$ and $b_n \uparrow d$.

Therefore, as measures have continuity from below, you have that

$$
\mu((c,d))=\mu\left(\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb N }(a_n,b_n]\right)=\lim_{n\to \infty}\mu((a_n,b_n])=\lim_{n\to\infty}(b_n-a_n)=d-c
$$

By a similar procedure, this time using the continuity from above given a starting set with finite measure, you can show that $\mu(\{x\})=0$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$. Hence $\mu=\lambda $ in all intervals, and so from the definition of the Lebesgue measure we find that $\mu=\lambda $ in the Borel $\sigma $-algebra.

Comment: This was much simpler and nicer! Thank you Sir